# Reading data from Android App using bluetooth

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-application-class

I have Java code to receive data in Android App via Bluetooth like the attached code

[Java Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfKrz.png)

so readMessage will equal = `{\"Pin\":\"A4\",\"Value\":\"20\"},{\"Pin\":\"A5\",\"Value\":\"925\"},{\"Pin\":\"A0\",\"Value\":\"30\"}`

So I want to take only the values after string `\"Value\"` from received data so

Can anyone suggest how to make do that?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post screenshots of your code. Please include the code directly in your question, as formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can parse the `readMessage` with [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format

example:

```
String[] pinValueArr = readMessage.split(",")
for (String pinValue : pinValueArr) {
    try {
        JSONObject pinValueJSON = new JSONObject(pinValue);
        String pin = pinValueJSON.optString("pin", "");  // opt means if parse failed, return default value what is ""
        int pin = pinValueJSON.optInt("Value", 0);   // opt means if parse failed, return default value what is "0"
    } catch (JSONParsedException e) {
        // catch exception when parse to JSONObject failed
    }
}
```

And if you want to manage them, you can make a `List` and add them all.

```
List<JSONObject> pinValueList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
for (String pinValue : pinValueArr) {
    JSONObject pinValueJSON = new JSONObject(pinValue);
    // ..
    pinValueList.add(pinValueJSON);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson to convert Json to Object.
(https://github.com/google/gson)

1. Create Model Class

```
data class PinItem(
           @SerializedName("Pin")
           val pin: String? = null,
           @SerializedName("Value")
           val value: String? = null
       )
```

2. Convert your json.

```
    val json = "[{"Pin":"A4","Value":"20"},{"Pin":"A5","Value":"925"},{"Pin":"A0","Value":"30"}]"

    val result =  Gson().fromJson(this, object : TypeToken<List<PinItem>>() {}.type)
```

3. So now you having list `PinItem` and you can get all info off it.